# Do your levels and stat records carry over between different region servers?

Tags: overwatch

Overwatch has different region servers, such as North America, Europe, Asia, etc.

If I'm level 50 with a competitive skill rating of 40 on the EU server, will my level, skill rating, and other stats that I've accumulated carry over if I start playing on the other region servers? Or will everything start over as if I'm a new player?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The stats levels etc is account related not region related. The only reason to pick your region (say America) over Asia is, servers will be near you and thus everyone will have similar ping and you won't be experiencing any lag.

This was an issue when Competitive made it to the Public Test Region, as that region's servers are in the US, people from other regions had ping issues while testing.

> **OVERWATCH GLOBAL PLAY**
>
> Global Play in Overwatch works differently from our other games. All of your game progress, including unlocked in-game items, remains the same across all regions.

[Source](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/6539)

Comment: Do you have a Source for that ? Starcraft and Hots have different accounts for you in different Regions so i would assume Overwatch doing the same. (for examle log into Hots on a different region and you don´t have all of your heroes)

Comment: @MartinH. I do, updated

Comment: And the reason you might pick a region other than your own - so you can play with online friends who are in a different region.

Comment: I know that much, but now it makes more sense :-D

Comment: This helped me allot, Now I'm able to get carried for the new Uprising PvE mode on NA and still get the achievement on EU